# Can I work on a github project between two machines with a usb?

Tags: github

So, I have a desktop and a laptop. I use both very frequently. I keep my work files on a usb and that is how I get to switch so easily between the two. Now I am beginning a project in which I use android studio and github. I am new to github.

Can I use github in conjunction with this usb drive between two computers or should I commit to using one computer? Will this create problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea behind GitHub is to avoid file transfer manually like that. If you want to do a project on both machines. Then...

1. Create a GitHub Repository
2. Pull your project from your repo (Do this on both Systems)
3. Every time you do something on one machine, before you switch to the next, commit your changes and then push them.

If you are new to Git and dont know how it works, then feel free to check out [GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/).

Comment: That's not the whole idea but it is one of the major advantages of using git.

Comment: Well i guess the "whole idea" would be for team integration more than anything, and trying to do it without having to swap flashdrives with your team.

Comment: I should pull everytime I start working then commit and push when I stop correct?

Comment: Yes, pull availible changes before you start, and push them once your done.